# What command to run for Live.ether.camp project?

Tags: ether, ide, ether-camp, ethereum-studio

and am trying to run the example-project in live.ether.com.
What is the command for me to run the project?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example project consists of 3 parts:

- Solidity contracts in directory contracts/
- Web-app in directory web/
- Tests for the contracts in directory test/

To run the contracts you need to start a new ethereum sandbox with your contracts deployed there. To do that click on "Run All Contract" button:

[image: run all contracts]

I think you're using IDE in the minimal mode. If so, you should have an arrow button to open the top panel with the "Run All Contracts" button:

[image]

There's README file that explains how to run the web-app and the tests (https://github.com/ether-camp/default-ws/blob/master/example-project/README.md). It provides shell commands, if you have any troubles using them, please ask.

Also, there's a great doc from Steve which has a page about the example project https://nogo10.gitbooks.io/ether-camp-live-studio-primer/content/running_your_app.html

Comment: Great help thank you! IDE was in minimal mode as  you said, now things look much better (not in minimal mode). Following docs now, got sandbox id, things are looking up, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Open the bash terminal, on your screenshot the most leftish tab below. And build the example project with the following commands:

```
cd ~/workspace/example-project
npm install gulp-cli -g
npm install
gulp
```

After that, to run it:

```
cd ~/workspace/example-project/web
npm install http-server -g
http-server
```

You will see some output like that:

```
Starting up http-server, serving ./
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
  http://172.17.0.45:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
[Wed Jun 22 2016 13:00:24 GMT+0000 (UTC)] "GET /" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"
[Wed Jun 22 2016 13:00:24 GMT+0000 (UTC)] "GET /dist/app.js" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"
[Wed Jun 22 2016 13:00:26 GMT+0000 (UTC)] "GET /favicon.ico" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"
[Wed Jun 22 2016 13:00:26 GMT+0000 (UTC)] "GET /favicon.ico" Error (404): "Not found"
[Wed Jun 22 2016 13:00:26 GMT+0000 (UTC)] "GET /favicon.ico" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"
[Wed Jun 22 2016 13:00:26 GMT+0000 (UTC)] "GET /favicon.ico" Error (404): "Not found"
```

To see the example application you go to the following URL: `https://5chdn.by.ether.camp:8080/`, but replace my nickname with yours.